# AspNet Identity 2: Customize OAuth endpoint response

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I successfully implemented my custom `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`. But when I log in and retrieve a token, my client doesn't have any idea of the user's roles, claims, etc.

I currently added a webapi controller to return the list of the principal's claims, but I'm not really happy with that.

When requesting a token, the current response looks like:

```
{
    access_token: "qefelgrebjhzefilrgo4583535",
    token_type: "bearer",
    expires_in: 59
}
```

**Q> How can make it return something like the following snippet?**

```
{
    access_token: "qefelgrebjhzefilrgo4583535",
    token_type: "bearer",
    expires_in: 59,
    user: {
        name: 'foo',
        role: 'bar'
    }
}
```

**My progress so far:**

The documentation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider#TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext)` says:

> Called at the final stage of a successful Token endpoint request. An application
>   may implement this call in order to do any final modification of the claims
>   being used to issue access or refresh tokens. This call may also be used
>   in order to add additional response parameters to the Token endpoint's json
>   response body.

I couldn't find any example of how to customize the response, and asp-net Identity's source code is not yet released, so I'm quite stuck.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

May be you are looking for `TokenEndpoint` method override of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`.

```cs
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I found the method but I didn't know how to add the properties to the response. I'll try that and accept the answers it that does the job

Comment: Your code works well, but when I try to return objects instead of top level values, I get an error 500. IIRC the spec (for OAuth2 or something) says that the token and stuff have to be top level values, so I guess that's why. Still I hoped there was more freedom for custom values. Anyway, that's the answer to my question, Thanks!

Comment: @scenario // Check out `CreateProperties` method in ApplicationOauthProvider.cs file and its related usage.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about the right way to pass my own properties to `#TokenEndpoint`. Doesn't help with returning complex objects though... I'll just try to avoid doing weird stuff and stick to the standards

Comment: @Youngjae's answer is correct: add a parameter to the create properties function for each thing you want to return and add it's value to the IDictionary object being created in the CreateProperties function

Comment: should that return statement be there? I get an error: "Error: return keyword must not be followed by an object expression" when it is there. I think, since this methods return type is Task, it should not return anything.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to override `TokenEndpointResponse` on `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class :

```
    public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("Key","Value");
        return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
    }
```

Comment: method `TokenEndpointResponse` can be better because it runs after the refresh token provider.